# Updating nav CSS on shell page when using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm working on a partial view web page using angularjs for the different states.

This is my main page where I will be loading in all the partial views. I have a side navbar used to navigate load in the views:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Settings</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="sidebar" class="sideStyle">
            <ul id="navList" class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active"><a data-ui-sref="settings.defaults">Defaults</a></li>
            <li><a data-ui-sref="settings.carriers"> Carriers</a></li>
            <li><a data-ui-sref="settings.trailers"> Trailers</a></li>
            <li><a data-ui-sref="settings.shifts">Shop Shifts</a></li>
            <li><a data-ui-sref="settings.bccap">Bend Class Capacities</a></li>
             </ul> 
        </div> 
        <div id="main" class="mainContent" style="padding-top:15px">
            <button onclick="toggleNav()" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs " id="btnToggle">
                <span class="toggleClass glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
            </button>

            <div>
                <div data-ui-view=""></div>  //where page is loaded in
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="AppScripts/Sidebar.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is a look at Sidebar.js:

```
var toggle, mainLeft;
function toggleNav() {
    if (toggle == 0) {
        toggle = 1;
        $("#sidebar").toggle('slide');
        $("#main").animate({
            left: "10",
        }, 350, function () { });
        $('.mainContent').animate({ width: '100%' }, 500);
        $('.toggleClass').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-right').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-left');
    }
    else {
        toggle = 0;
        $("#sidebar").toggle('slide');
        $("#main").animate({
            left: mainLeft,
        }, 350, function () { });
        $('.mainContent').animate({ width: '85%' }, 500);
        $('.toggleClass').addClass('glyphicon-chevron-left').removeClass('glyphicon-chevron-right');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var left = $('#sidebar').width();
    mainLeft = left + 50;
    $('#main').css({ left: mainLeft });

    toggle = 0;

    $('#btnToggle span').addClass('glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'); 
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#navList li').click(function () {
        $(this).siblings('li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

And my navigation CSS:

```
/* Sidebar navigation */
.nav-sidebar {
  margin-right: -21px; /* 20px padding + 1px border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.nav-sidebar > li > a {
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color:#8b6d80;
}
.nav-sidebar > .active > a {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #8b6d80;
}

.listItem {
background-color:whitesmoke;
font-size:medium;
}

.selectedItem {
border-left:solid 5px;
border-color:#8b6d80;
background-color:#EEEEEE;
font-size:medium;
}
```

I'm setting the clicked link with a CSS class "active" to make apparent what link they have clicked. Angularjs is very nice where it remembers the users breadcrumbs and takes care of loading the correct page when the back button is used. However since my nav is in the shell page and not the partial view, the nav has the incorrect link marked as "active" wehn the back button is used:

Here are some screen shots to show what I mean:

On trailers page:

[image]

Navigated to carriers page and then press back button:
[image]

What would be the best way of making sure the correct link is "active" since the shell isn't being refreshed and the link isn't actually being clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to set the active class using [`ng-class directive`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

So your html will look something along the lines of

```
<ul id="navList" class="nav nav-sidebar">
  <li ng-class="{ active: isRoute('/settings/defaults') }"><a data-ui-sref="settings.defaults">Defaults</a></li>
  <li ng-class="{ active: isRoute('/settings/carriers') }"><a data-ui-sref="settings.carriers"> Carriers</a></li>
  <li ng-class="{ active: isRoute('/settings/trailers') }"><a data-ui-sref="settings.trailers"> Trailers</a></li>
  <li ng-class="{ active: isRoute('/settings/shifts') }"><a data-ui-sref="settings.shifts">Shop Shifts</a></li>
  <li ng-class="{ active: isRoute('/settings/bccap') }"><a data-ui-sref="settings.bccap">Bend Class Capacities</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then in your controller. You will need a function that checks the current path and returns true or false (depending if it matches). This could be accomplished with using the $location service.

Ex:

```
app.yourController(['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
  $scope.isRoute = function(path) {
    return $location.path() == path;
  };
}]);
```

This should be sufficient. (I use a similar tactic in my app, and it works just fine).

Using this, you wont need the function that listens to each nav's click event.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already answered, but it's also worth saying that this is the whole point behind ui-sref-active, may not be entirely applicable here because of your nested jquery page integration, but in a typical ui-router state setup, this is the exact purpose of this directive, so I thought I'd leave it here for future readers

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref-active